Onclick event not working in datatable1.10 after html gets altered via responsive mode
I'm using datatables 1.10 with responsive mode. There is a button in each row that i've added an onclick even for in the document.ready() function. However when the screen width gets smaller and the datatable goes into responsive mode, the onclick no longer works. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is my onclick event:
$('a[href="#"]').click(function () {}

This is the table row before the responsive css alters it (onclick event works):
<tr class="odd dt-hasChild parent">
    <td class="text-center" style="">
       <a href="#" id="61" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Review</a>
    </td>
<tr>

This is the table row after the responsive css alters it (onclick event does not work):
<tr class="odd dt-hasChild parent">
    <td class="text-center" style="">
       <a href="#" id="61" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Review</a>
    </td>
<tr>
<tr class="odd dt-hasChild child">
    <td class="text-center" style="">
       <a href="#" id="61" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Review</a>
    </td>
<tr>


Are you rewriting the HTML by assigning to .innerHTML (or calling jQuery .html()?). That will destroy any event listeners in the elements that get overwritten. Use event delegation instead of binding directly to the elements that get rewritten.
